# windows XP. Laptop sees router, however cannot connect to the internet

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking

This laptop had been working fine up till a couple of days ago. Now, it wont actually connect to the internet although the wireless network connection shows it to be connected with a strong signal.

I had been following a similar thread, but when it came to the bit where you go into the command line prompts I couldn't progress any further after entering ipconfig. See below

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Jim.HPLAPTOP>ipconfig
Windows IP configuration
An internal error occurred: The request is not supported.
Please contact Microsoft Support Services for further help.
Additional information: Unable to query host name
C:\Documents and Settings\Jim.HPLAPTOP>
```

Any help would be appreciated in restoring my old laptop to its former glory!

Thanks

jsphd

Comment: Try to provide Event Log info by running "eventvwr.msc" and check for alerts on the `System` section. This info could show you the method: http://deinfotech.blogspot.com.es/2012/02/ipconfigan-internal-error-occurred.html

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be caused by a missing or corrupted `ipsec.sys` .

Chceck if you have one located in `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\ipsec.sys` and if not, either:

- Copy it from another machine with the same Windows version, or
- Download the latest service pack on a computer with network connectivity ([SP3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24)) and extract the file, or
- Run sfc (System File Checker) using `sfc /scannow` as an Administrator, which might be able to restore the file.